# Android webview save images to device

Tags: android, image-caching

I have a webapp with some quite heavy images and they took a while to load

Is possible to save images from a website to an android device and then load them in a webview?

Thanks

Comment: WebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled ?

Comment: yes, I have that setting, but it works while the app is onbackground, if I stop it, and try to get in again it just reload the imgs

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to save images from a website to an android device?

> Yes, using [file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305659/save-image-locally-in-android) or a [sqllitedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)-databae

then load them in a webview?

> This can be achieved with following method:
>
> - public void [loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)
>
> An example how to display an image using loadData:
>
> - [How to display image with WebView loaddata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267124/how-to-display-image-with-webview-loaddata)
> - [Save image locally and display in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013504/save-image-locally-and-display-in-webview)

Hope this helps, if not comment below